# How do I check for empty tags while parsing xml?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nullpointerexception

I am using the Document object to extract all the tags from an xml. If the xml has an empty tag, I get a null pointer exception. How do I guard against this? How do I check for an empty tag?

```
<USTrade>
<CreditorId>
<CustomerNumber>xxxx</CustomerNumber>
<Name></Name>
<Industry code="FY" description="Factor"/>
</CreditorId>
<DateReported format="MM/CCYY">02/2012</DateReported>
<AccountNumber>54000</AccountNumber>
<HighCreditAmount>0000299</HighCreditAmount>
<BalanceAmount>0000069</BalanceAmount>
<PastDueAmount>0000069</PastDueAmount>
<PortfolioType code="O" description="Open Account (30, 60, or 90 day account)"/>
<Status code="5" description="120 Dys or More PDue"/>
 <Narratives>
<Narrative code="GS" description="Medical"/>
<Narrative code="CZ" description="Collection Account"/>
</Narratives>
</USTrade>
<USTrade>
```

So, when I use:

```
                NodeList nm = docElement.getElementsByTagName("Name");
                if (nm.getLength() > 0)
                    name = nullIfBlank(((Element) nm.item(0))
                            .getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```

Nodelist gives a length of 1, because there is a tag, but when I do getTextContent(), it hits the null pointer because FirstChild() doesn't return anything for tag = Name

And, I have done this for each xml tag. Is there a simple check I can do before every tag extraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I would do would be to unchain your calls. This will give you the chance to determine exactly which reference is null and which reference you need to do a null check for:

```
 NodeList nm = docElement.getElementsByTagName("Name");
                if (nm.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node n = nm.item(0);
                    Node child = n.getFirstChild();
                    if(child == null) {
                        // null handling
                        name = null;
                     }
                    else {
                       name = nullIfBlank(child.getTextContent());
                    }

                 }
```

Also, check out the `hasChildNodes()` method on Node! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#hasChildNodes%28%29

Comment: unfortunately, this will be the only way I can protect the code.

Comment: Some python alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(current != null){
                if(current.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    String nodeName = current.getNodeName();
                    System.out.println("\tNode: "+nodeName);
                    NamedNodeMap attributes = current.getAttributes();
                    System.out.println("\t\tNumber of Attributes: "+attributes.getLength());
                    for(int i=0; i<attributes.getLength(); i++){
                        Node attr = attributes.item(i);
                        String attName = attr.getNodeName();
                        String attValue= attr.getNodeValue();
                        System.out.println("\t\tAttribute Name: "+ attName+ "\tAttribute Value:"+ attValue);
                    }
                }
```

Are you also wanting to print out the value of the node? If so, it's one line of code in my example you would have to add, and I can share that as well.

Comment: My answer doesn't care if you know how many elements there are or not. Some of the other answers may be more pertinent if you want to actually specify each element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like that?

```
NodeList nm = docElement.getElementsByTagName("Name");
if ((Element) nm.item(0))
 name = nullIfBlank(((Element) nm.item(0)).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```

Comment: yeah, but if no tag of type Name exist, then nm.item(0) will result in null pointer.